Error running a VertexAI model with Langflow
I have a problem while running my Vertex AI model with langflow althogh I have created an account service and generated a key and the credentials json file. I always get this error
" Error building vertex VertexAI: Unable to authenticate your request. Depending on your runtime environment, you can complete authentication by: - if in local JupyterLab instance: !gcloud auth login - if in Colab: -from google.colab import auth -auth.authenticate_user() - if in service account or other: please follow guidance in https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication"
Can anyone please help me resolve this problem?
I tried generating a key via GCP but couldn't fix the problem

I had to set the location of the JSON credentials file
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path.json

